# How to keep track of a previous value within a method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

I need to compare a current integer with a previous integar within a method. It seems like something like this should work, but it doesn't. Can someone tell me where the problem lies? Note current is set outside the method.

```
myMethod : function() {
    var previous;

    if ( current > previous ) {
        // do this!
    }

    previous = current;
}
```

Comment: where is current defined? and what do you mean by "it doesn't"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you call `myMethod`, `previous` is declared anew (`var previous`).

You have four possibilities:

(A) Create a closure (best solution imo, but depends on your needs):

```
myMethod : (function() {
    var previous = null;
    return function() {
        if ( current > previous ) {
            // do this!
        }  
        previous = current;
    }
}());
```

(B) Set `previous` as property of the function object:

```
myMethod : function() {
    if ( current > foo.myMethod.previous ) {
        // do this!
    }   
    foo.myMethod.previous = current;
}

foo.myMethod.previous = null;
```

But this ties the function very much to the naming of the object.

(C) If it fits in your model, make `previous` a property of the object `myMethod` is a property of:

```
previous: null,
myMethod : function() {
    if ( current > this.previous ) {
        // do this!
    }
    this.previous = current;
}
```

(D) Similar to (A), set `previous` somewhere outside in a higher scope:

```
var previous = null;
// ...
myMethod : function() {

    if ( current > previous ) {
        // do this!
    }  
    previous = current;
}
```

This is not a good imo as it pollutes the higher scope.

Without seeing more of your code it is hard to tell, but it is probably also better when you pass `current` to the function.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd use the first idea?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to maintain state.

```
var previousState = 'something';

function myMethod(current)
{
    if(current > previousState)
       // Do Something

    previousState = current;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are trying to implement a memoization function. There is a good tutorial on how to go about it [here](http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/05/01/a-better-javascript-memoizer/).